# How to manage code changes in rails with docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I use this Dockerfile to make a rails app container:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

# for postgres
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
# for nokogiri
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
# for a JS runtime
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install
ADD . $APP_HOME
```

Now this loads my entire code into the image. When I make a code change in a file, do I have to run docker build again and start a new container to see the changes reflected? This seems bulky for quick changes and development.

Or should I mount the volume in my container for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should mount your code from outside of the Docker container to `/myapp` and then use `!reload` to have your Rails application restart whenever your code changes.

Comment: what do you mean by `!reload`